# Converting QuickReport To FastReport

Tags: delphi, migration, fastreport, quickreports

I am Converting a QuickReport to a FastReport in Delphi source, I want to determine the event method name that assigned to a QuickReport object and according to it assign a method to the same event of the FastReport object.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Fast Report has `ConverterQR2FR.pas` unit, which you could use to convert QR reports to FR, you can use it as :

```
conv := TConverterQr2Fr.Create;
conv.Source := QuickRep1;
conv.Target := FReport;
conv.Convert;
FReport.SaveToFile('converted_fromQR.fr3');
```

Comment: I'm using this unit, but this doesn't assign any event to objects.

Answer (score 3):

In QuickReport you were able to set events for things like TQrLabel, and those events lived in the Delphi unit's code. With FastReport you can do the same, but the event lives within the FastReport Report, not in the Delphi unit (FastReport includes an Pascal scripting engine). Because of this you'll probably need to copy your events by hand from the unit to the FastReport script.

Since this requires manual work, you might reconsider the reasons you originally used those events: FastReport might have better ways of doing the same thing without coding.